# How do i get rid of the "Cutout" look when i press tab in WPF

Tags: wpf

Hello I am trying to suppress the Cutout look in WPF. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIu36.gif)

I have tried using KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation and tried tab indexing maybe i'm doing it wrong. I just dont want the cutout look to display to the user any ides would help.

Comment: have you tried setting Focusable="False" and/or IsTabStop="False" for the control?

Comment: @Spongebrot  I'll Try

Comment: @Spongebrot Did not work!

Answer (score 1):

That "cutout" look is coming from the a focus style. You can remove the focus style by setting the `FocusVisualStyle`on the control that is displaying the "cutout" look. For example,

```
<StackPanel FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
```

Comment: Thanks can i just set that in my user control and do it for all of them.

Comment: Yeah. You could also set it in the default `Style` for the `UserControl`.

Comment: Thanks for you assistance.